# Getting Table Row with JSoup

Tags: android, jsoup

Im using JSoup with android and so far I have been successful. In my original activity I referenced a table and from that each individual cell in a table by code. My question is how would I have Jsoup get the results of a table based on some parameter?

For example if I wanted to get the 3rd row of a table - ( get its contents ). Any resources beside whats on the Jsoup site would do as I find that hard to follow.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an example URL we can play with?

Comment: Yes it's this: http://www.heavens-above.com/PassSummary.aspx?satid=25544&lat=54.5156&lng=-6.06863&loc=Unspecified&alt=0&tz=GMT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
    String html = "<table id=\"myTable\"><tr><td>First</td></tr><tr><td>Second</td></tr><tr><td>Third</td></tr></table>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    System.out.println(doc.select("#myTable").select("tr").get(1));
```

Output:

```
<tr>
 <td>Second</td>
</tr>
```

That is the second row in the table.

Comment: this worked well, thanks. But is there anyway to get the total number of rows in the table?

Comment: Sorry - I got it :D it's just .size() instead of .get()

Answer (score 2):

Try

"table tr:eq(3)"

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax